# TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: ['article_name'] of type <class 'list'>

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I think I have a question that is not that difficult but I cannot find an answer to this online. :(
So I hope anyone can help me here.

I am writing a function that calculates the amount of customers that buys a product inside a category. For example how many customers buys Cola inside Drinks?

It should be possible to give more columns as input value for the article value, so for example article number and article name. But when I only give one column as input value, it returns the next error:

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback       (most recent call last)
<command-107291202997552> in <module>
 ----> 1 raf=penetration_test(df_source,"customer_hash", ["article_name"])
      2 display(raf)

<command-1757898160611556> in penetration_test(input_dataframe, customer_column, product_columns, penetration_category, attach_penetration_columns)
     64     else:
     65         penetration_dataframe = input_dataframe.select(
---> 66             array(col_list)
     67         ).distinct()
     68     return penetration_dataframe

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py in array(*cols)
   2998     if len(cols) == 1 and isinstance(cols[0], (list, set)):
   2999         cols = cols[0]
-> 3000     jc = sc._jvm.functions.array(_to_seq(sc, cols, _to_java_column))
   3001     return Column(jc)
   3002 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py in _to_seq(sc, cols, converter)
     60     """
     61     if converter:
---> 62         cols = [converter(c) for c in cols]
     63     return sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(cols)
     64 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     60     """
     61     if converter:
---> 62         cols = [converter(c) for c in cols]
     63     return sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(cols)
     64 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py in _to_java_column(col)
     44         jcol = _create_column_from_name(col)
     45     else:
---> 46         raise TypeError(
     47             "Invalid argument, not a string or column: "
     48             "{0} of type {1}. "

TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: ['article_name'] of type <class 'list'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

For this I wrote the following function (I will just give the lines that are interestant for my question):

```
def penetration_test(input_dataframe, customer_column="customer_hash",
     product_columns=["hope_number", "article_number"],
     penetration_category="category_number",attach_penetration_columns=False,
):        

     col_list = []
     col_list.append("category_number")
     if len(product_columns) >1:
       for item in product_columns:
         col_list.append(item)
     else:
       col_list.append(product_columns)
     
     #display penetration
     penetration_dataframe = input_dataframe.select(
        col_list
     ).distinct()
     return penetration_dataframe
```

This is the code that I execute that returns an error.

```
df_res = penetration_test(df_source,"customer_hash", ["article_name"], "category_name", False)
display(df_res)
```

Can someone help me to solve the problem?

Comment: Please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message, by copying and pasting, starting from the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):` until the end, and formatting it like code. Also, please [try to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) solve the problem yourself first, by [tracing the code execution to understand what goes wrong](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), reading documentation for the libraries you are using, and using a search engine to look up anything you don't understand.

Comment: I have added the complete error message. I am trying to find the solution for the whole morning but could not find it... that's why I posted my question here

Comment: The error message shown does not match the code shown. In particular, it shows that `array(col_list)` is used, where the posted code just says `col_list`. That said: try to check the value of `col_list` right before the `input_dataframe.select` call. Do you know what it should look like? Does it look right? Then try to think about why that is. (Hint: as it says in the Zen of Python, `special cases aren't special enough`. What is the intended purpose of the first block of code? Should the logic actually be different `if len(product_columns) >1` or not? Why?)

Comment: sorry, I posted the error message from a previous run. The if len(product_columns) >1 was the problem, I deleted this and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, instead of iterating to `.append` each item of a list to another list, that is what `.extend` is for. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/.